# failed to upgrad from 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 14.10

I am connected to the net all the time. I am able to download several packages and than the download stops and I am getting the next message:

```
Could not download the upgrades
The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have been kept.
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/aptdaemon/aptdaemon-data_1.1.1+bzr980-0ubuntu1_all.deb Unable to connect to il.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/aptdaemon/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1+bzr980-0ubuntu1_all.deb Unable to connect to il.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/packagekit/libpackagekit-glib2-16_0.8.17-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb Unable to connect to il.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/packagekit/gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0_0.8.17-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb Unable to connect to il.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/aptdaemon/python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat_1.1.1+bzr980-0ubuntu1_all.deb Unable to connect to il.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-setuptools/python3-pkg-resources_5.5.1-1_all.deb Unable to connect to il.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/aptdaemon/aptdaemon_1.1.1+bzr980-0ubuntu1_all.deb Unable to connect to il.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading from another mirror:

## GUI

- Open the Software Centre
- Click: Edit > Software Sources
- Find the dropdown menu "Download From"
- select Other
- select a mirror

## Command Line

- Open /etc/apt/sources.list (sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list)
- Locate http://XX.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
- Replace it with another token http://YY.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

You can also use this tool to generate a custom sources.list: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: will be happy if someone write that this solution works - I can't check  - every time I got the mentioned error I started the upgrade again and it started from where it left before... it took a lot of time to do it over and over again but finally I got the upgrade...